# When are iptables bytes counters cleared?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables

When are iptables byte counters reset? On reboot or other rotation?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

On reboot, or whenever you ask them to be cleared with the `-Z` option to iptables.

Comment: Also if the entry is changed in any way, 
    iptables -R INPUT 5 -j LOG
... line 5's counters will be reset so as to properly reflect that it is a counter of what matches the function of the line.

Answer (score 7):

On reboot, when -Z is called or when a table is flushed (-F). Counters are also reset if you run "/etc/init.d/iptables stop" on RHEL or CentOS (because it flushes all default chains).